# moveend event fired many times when page is load with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I need to do some operations when the map is paned or zoomed, so I attached a callback to the event **moveend**.

```
map.on('moveend', function() {
    // code stuff
});
```

It works fine, but when the page is load the event is fired three times and I don't know why.
Probably because during its creation the map is moved.

To avoid this i tried to wait the **load** event before subscribing moveend event, but nothing changed. So I tried to attach it within *whenReady* callaback, but again it is fired three times.

```
map.whenReady(function() {
    map.on('moveend', function() {
        // code stuff
    });
});
```

Finally, I discovered that after the **resize** event it works quite fine: *moveend* is fired jonly one time. But I really believe there is a best way to fix the problem.

Another solution could be to attach my callback to both events **zoomend** and **dragend**, to cover paning and zooming cases.
But I didn't find a way to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the **first** resize event only, something like `map.once('resize', ...)`?

Comment: Thank you Oleg, yes I think it. But I would prefer a clearer solution if it exist

Comment: Moreover, attaching the *resize* event, *moveend* is fired still one time

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The best solution I found is to attach the callback to both events:

```
    map.on('zoomend', function() {
        // callback
    });

    map.on('dragend', function() {
        // callback
    });
```

Although this way the code is a bit replicated, this is by far the best solution.

Comment: Right, but you would need to debounce this where idle already does that for you.

Comment: I use react-leaflet and `onMoveEnd` was causing my React components to crash due to too many updates. Switching to `onDragEnd` and `onZoomEnd` as suggested by @Guern solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

For others looking into this, research the `options.debounceMoveend` option on the `invalidateSize` function.  It's [mentioned in briefly](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-invalidatesize) in the documentation, but unfortunately it looks like it's only for that function, rather than generally for the `moveend` event.

> [...] If **options.debounceMoveend** is **true**, it will delay **moveend** event so that it doesn't happen often even if the method is called many times in a row.

[Reference to the line in source code (L3541)](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/0e566b2ad5e696ba9f79a9d48a7e51c8f4892441/dist/leaflet-src.js#L3541)

Answer (score 0):

The 'zoomend' and 'dragend' option didn't work for me. I searched a lot for a suitable option and realized that the "moveend" event fires several times because this event is created every time you move the map. Therefore it is necessary to stop this event. I got out of the situation in this way.
Immediately after the map was initialized, I wrote:

```
map.off('moveend');
```

and for me it worked. Now it works fine.
I will be very happy if this is useful to someone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.
Example:

```js
block.addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>{
    //some code when hover
})

block.addEventListener('mouseleave', ()=>{
    // some code when leaving block
})
```

[link to developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event)